# The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'System.Management-Automation' is not installed on this computer

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Power shell version 4.0 under windows server 2012.. now I run the following powershell command :-

```
$admin = "domain\user"
$pwd = "*****" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management-Automation.PSCredential($admin, $pwd)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName **** -Credential $LiveCred {Get-VM}
```

but I got this error :-

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Management-Automation.PSCredential]: verify that the assembly containing this
type is loaded.
```

so I updated my powershell script as follow:-

```
add-pssnapin System.Management-Automation;
$admin = "domain\user"
$pwd = "*****" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management-Automation.PSCredential($admin, $pwd)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName **** -Credential $LiveCred {Get-VM}
```

But I got this error instead :-

```
add-pssnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'System.Management-Automation' is not installed on this computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ add-pssnapin System.Management-Automation;
```

so can anyone advice what is causing the above 2 errors ?

second question is there a more straight forward way to pass the password inside the `Invoke-Command` ? now I can pass the username as follow:-

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName **** -Credential domain\username {Get-VM}
```

but not sure if I can pass the password in the same way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a hyphen where you should have a period. There is no class `System.Management-Automation`, it's `System.Management.Automation`:

```
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($admin, $pwd)
```